# TableView and Storyboards

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an iphone app where I set a main table according to data received over the internet:

```
bList = [[BeerList alloc] initListWithData:array];
[mainTable setDataSource:bList];
[mainTable setDelegate:bList];
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"BLAH  %@",mainTable]);
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"BLAH1 %@",[mainTable dataSource]]);
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"BLAH2 %@",[mainTable delegate]]);
[self.mainTable reloadData];
```

And in the BeerList:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
//We only have a single section
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"HERESS = %d",[tableData count]]);
return [tableData count];
}
```

and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSLog(@"We be here");
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"Blah";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
}
NSUInteger cnt = [tableData count];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",[[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"brewery_name"],[[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"beer_name"]];

return cell;
}
```

Which works fine in the first views. I have a secondary view controller which alters some properties and returns to this initial view. On the return to the initial view the table doesn't redraw. Though the request for "numberOfRowsInSection" returns a positive number, the cells don't appear in the UI. Is there something weird about storyboards that would cause this?

Comment: Can you post the code that get's run when the app returns to the "initial view"? Also, not sure what you mean by: `Though the request for "numberOfRowsInSection" returns a positive number, the cells don't appear in the UI.`.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I don't understand storyboards properly. But from the logs it would seem that the view calls the "numberOfRowsInSection" method but then never calls the method to retrieve the cell details

Comment: You might need to reload table on viewDidAppear. When you come back from secondary view, primary view ( Tableview in your case ) in not redrawn.